# How do I skip commercial ads in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

It is irritating to have to wait another 21 sec for my video to start playing.

Any idea how to block these ads? They have no fast-forward button.

[image: Screenshot from YouTube]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This chrome extension maybe help you:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en

[image]

Comment: It seems this extension only hides the video ad, but does not skip it. Am I correct?

Comment: According to the extension changes log, from version 2.0 ads completely blocked from downloading.
"- New in version 2.0: Ads are blocked from downloading, instead of just being removed after the fact!"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/details?hl=en

Comment: @arshen adblock is not reliable the video is restarting automatically